# Copy restricted files using shutil.copyfile without being root in Python

Tags: python, shutil

One of the task that my python script does is to extract an entire Linux Root FS tarball and then copy files from it into a destination directory. While doing so, I am getting the error in case of special restricted files (like gshadow) as follow:

```
File "script.py", line 553, in copy_rootfs
shutil.copy(sourceFileName,targetFileName)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 88, in copy
copyfile(src, dst)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/temp/home/embeduser/NFS/LinuxFS/etc/gshadow'
```

Permissions for the file gshadow extracted from tarball is as follow:

```
myuser@host temp]$ ls -l home/embeduser/NFS/LinuxFS/etc/gshadow 
---------- 1 myuser myuser 271 Nov  5 08:54 home/embeduser/NFS/LinuxFS/etc/gshadow
```

Is there a way I can achieve this without having to run my python script as root?

Comment: Nope. Noone is allowed to read that file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, not necessarily - if the setting of permissions can be separated from the copying of the file itself, the permissions could be set after all copying is complete. I don't know enough about `shutil` to know if that's possible though.

Comment: Post your code, @modest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `shutil`, but it's easy enough to come up with some custom solution.  The trick is that `gshadow` has no permissions, but belongs to the local user.  So you can change its permissions with `os.chmod()`, read it, then (if necessary) change the permissions back.

Comment: OK, I see. Is there a way in Python to detect these kind of files? It would be very cumbersome to explicitly check for special files by their names.

Comment: You call `os.lstat()` on them and check if the premissions you get include or not the bit that means "readable by the user".